# Safari CSS positioning rules seem mutually exclusive to that of other browsers

Tags: html, css

I have some CSS that looks fine in Chrome and Firefox, but is turning up a specific problem in Safari.  The three divs/ul items are aligning properly in Chrome and Firefox, but are stacking directly on top of each other in Safari.  To make it look right in Sf, I can make the left margin progressively larger between the three, but the result in FF and Chrome is that the divs go way off the page.  I have tried a few hacks including this one:

```
 @media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0){}
```

This didn't change anything.  So here's the relevant HTML:

```
 <ul id="nav">
   <li class="nav_item"><div id= "work">&nbsp;</div></li>

   <li class="nav_item"><div id="about">&nbsp;</div></li>

   <li class="nav_item"><div id="contact">&nbsp;</div></li>
</ul>
```

...And the CSS:

```
 #work{  height: 50px;
         width: 68px;
     font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 24px;
    background-color: none;
    background-image: url(work_1.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 120%;
    position: fixed;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 201;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    margin: 1px 1px 1px 40px;
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    float:right;}


 #about{ height: 50px;
    width: 68px;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 24px;
    background-color: none;
    background-image: url(about.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 120%;
    position: fixed;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 201;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    margin: 1px 1px 1px 40px;
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    float: right;}

 #contact{ height: 50px;
    width: 84px;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 24px;
    background-color: none;
    background-image: url(contact.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 200;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    margin: 1px 1px 1px 40px;
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    float:right;}

 #nav {

   padding: 0px;
   display:inline;
   list-style-type:none;
   margin: 30px 0px 0px 700px;
   position:fixed;
   width:600px;


}

 .nav_item {
          display:inline !important;
    position:relative !important;
    margin: 5px 5px 5px 150px;
    width:100px;
    display: inline !important;
}
```

Comment: it would probably be worth specifying the browser versions you're testing with.

Comment: I didn't think to check earlier, but it's 5.1.3. for Sf and the latest versions for Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: That's kind of an old version of Safari. On the latest version, the layout is the same as in Chrome and FF. But your code doesn't give much away. It would be better to provide a proper working example.